# Ignore rewriting a directory is not working properly

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a weird situation where a rule is working on a different domain with the same host but it won't work on a specific domain.

I have 2x Bluehost accounts, they are a standard cheap shared hosting provider.

On account #1 I have a single hosted account which has 4 domain names. 1 domain is the primary domain (loads off the /public_html/ directory of the account) and 3 add-on domains which are just folders inside of /public_html/.

On account #1 I have this in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

That is located directly under where I ignore rewriting some file extensions and after that I have a bunch of url rewrite rules which are all working.

On account #1 this all works fine.

On account #2 I have the same exact setup but the add-on domains are throwing error 500s when accessing them, it also does not add error.log entries in the folder of the files and I tested the domain without rewriting and it works fine. They are accessible through standard urls (www.example.com) so it's not like it's a sub-domain or anything.

This add-on domain in this case is very basic. It's just a single page domain with no rewriting rules. If I delete the .htaccess from the primary domain then the sub domain works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that was quick. In the add-on domain I did NOT have an .htaccess file. I figured this would be ok because I wasn't doing any re-writing.

Apparently it does not work like that. I added an .htaccess to that add-on domain's folder and added this on top like usual:

```
RewriteEngine On
```

Now both domains are working as intended.